# Plotting differential equation in python

Tags: python, differential-equations

I'm trying to plot the differential equation dh/dt = I(t) - f(h)*h(t), where f(h) can be modeled with f(h) = 1 - e^(-kh), with k being a constant. How can I go about this?

Comment: you should utilise numpy https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/index.html#reference and matplotlib https://matplotlib.org

Answer (score 0):

Using [numpy (supports differential equations)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) alongside [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/), you should be able to achieve this. Numpy supports all sorts of [mathematical functions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.math.html), including trigonometric functions, derivitaves, integrals, etc. Once your equation is finalized, with all variables (set K equal to whatever, or solve for K using algebra), you can graph a mathematical function in Matplotlib - [here is a guide](https://www.scriptverse.academy/tutorials/python-matplotlib-plot-function.html). In short, solve the equation using numpy, then graph with matplotlib.